# Two HTML DATETIME fields in a form. End time/date must be greater than Start time/date

Tags: c#, html, validation, datetime

I am creating a time card site for employees to enter the hours they worked during the day, and on what task. The end datetime entered needs to be greater(or later) than the start datetime, but I am unable to find any HTML attributes or C# model validations to do so.

Html:

```
<form action="PunchIn" method="POST">
            <span asp-validation-for="Task"></span>
            <p>Today's Task</p>
            <input type="text" name="Task" required>
            <br>
            <p>Time Started</p>
            <input type="datetime-local" name="TimeIn" required>
            <br>
            <p>Time Ended</p>
            <input type="datetime-local" name="TimeOut" required>
            <br>
            <button class="InButton">Punch In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can do that on the back end on form submit and compare the 2 values if one is not greater then the other return an error.

Comment: @Brad Would that be using the C# [Compare] method? What would the syntax be for comparing greater/lesser than?

Comment: Check this out:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95895/how-to-check-if-one-datetime-is-later-than-another-in-c-sharp, but you would have to convert the string value from the form to a datetime first for this to work

Comment: And this can be used dynamically with the HTML Form inputs?

Comment: If you grab the values of the inputted values on the form submit into variables and validate, then if one is not greater than the other, stop the form submission and display an error